# Using JavaScript API 3.10 with ArcGIS Server 10.6

Tags: arcgis-js-api

We are upgrading our ArcGIS server to 10.6 but do not have the resources to upgrade our JavaScript client which is still on 3.10. We plan to upgrade to the latest version of the JavaScript API in the future but it won't be part of this current project.  Does anyone know of any compatibility issues we should be aware of between JavaScript API 3.10 and ArcGIS server 10.6?

Comment: What version of Server were you using before?

There are no compatibility issues that i'm aware of. The Javascript API is basically just a client-side library that makes HTTP requests to the server using the REST API. Most of the major features of the REST API were introduced in 10.0.

Comment: We are currently on 10.2.2 which works fine with JavaScript 3.10.  The only reason I posted this question was because I found some incompatibilities between the 4.1 version of the JavaScript API and Server 10.2.2.  Hopefully we won't run into any problems staying on the 3.10 version of JavaScript with the 10.6 version of Server.